# Decoding HTML and databinding into a ASP.NET repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a separate page where I use the Server.HTMLEncode feature to encode HTML a user has entered inside of a HTMLEditorExtender on a TextBox.

I am trying to insert this HTML into a repeater like so:

```
<asp:Repeater id="articleList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="itemtemplate">

        <h2><%#Container.DataItem("Title")%></h2>

        <h5>Category:</h5> <%#Container.DataItem("Category")%><br />
        <%#Container.DataItem("decodedHTML")%>
        <%#Container.DataItem("UserName")%>
        <%#Container.DataItem("DateOfPost")%>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <div class="altitemtemplate">
     <h2><%#Container.DataItem("Title")%></h2>

        <h5>Category:</h5> <%#Container.DataItem("Category")%><br />
        <%#Container.DataItem("decodedHTML")%>
        <%#Container.DataItem("UserName")%>
        <%#Container.DataItem("DateOfPost")%>
    </div>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And my code behind:

```
Sub displayArticles()
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [UserArticles] ORDER BY DateOfPost DESC", conn)
    Dim inputString As String = "HTMLBody"
    Dim decodedHTML As String = Server.HtmlDecode(inputString)
    articleList.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    articleList.DataBind()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

"HTMLBody" is the name of the field in my database with the encoded HTML in.

Unfortunately, I am receiving the error

```
"IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code".
```

There is obviously a problem here referring to the string decodedHTML in my Container.DataItem statement, so what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: code from the other page where the html is encoded:

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
        ErrorMessage.Visible = True
        ErrorMessage.Text = "Your submission is blank. Please write your article first"
        Else
            Dim oleDbConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
            Dim SqlString As String = "Insert into UserArticles(Title,Category,UserName,DateOfPost,HTMLPost) Values (@f1,@f2,@f3,@f4,@f5)"
            Dim HTMLEncode As String = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text)
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, oleDbConn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", ArticleTitle.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", CategoryDropDown.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", User.Identity.Name)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f4", DateTime.Now.Date)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f5", HTMLEncode)
            oleDbConn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            TextBox1.Text = Nothing
            ArticleTitle.Text = Nothing
            CategoryDropDown.ClearSelection()
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, `decodedHTML` is just a string which you are creating in the code. This is not accessible through your .aspx page.

You should just be able to update your .aspx markup to;

```
<%#Server.HtmlDecode(Container.DataItem("[COLUMN_NAME"))%>
```

Where [COLUMN_NAME] is the actual Table Column which holds the encoded html value.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use your example above (like so: <%#Server.HtmlDecode(Container.DataItem("HTMLPost"))%>) but it doesn't display any decoded html?

Comment: When you have `<%#Container.DataItem("HTMLPost")%>` is anything displayed?

Comment: Yes, for example this was displayed: <h1>meme</h1>

Comment: (I have edited my answer with the code from the page where the encode happens)

Comment: At the end of what? Like this: <%#Server.HtmlDecode(Container.DataItem("HTMLPost")).ToString()%> ?

Comment: It still outputs it this way: <h1>me</h1>
<img src="/img/ar/main problems encountered.PNG">

Comment: Like that `<%#Server.HtmlDecode(Container.DataItem("HTMLPost").ToString())%>`

Comment: It still outputs it decoded as opposed to in HTML? If you take a look at my encoding sub is there anything untowards going on there? I also thought it might be because I'm using Access as my database (field type for the HTML string is set to "Long Text"). I have also set sanitization for the htmleditorextender to off as it is not a public website